# Substituir um valor de um índice na matriz Python

Tags: python-3.x, lista, matriz, slice

Olá, pessoal..
Estou com uma dúvida de como construir um código onde possuo uma matriz de 8x5 e a cada inserção de um valor (input informado pelo usuário) já presente na matriz eu consiga localizar este valor e substitui-lo por x ou ' '.
Pensei em fazer fatiamento da matriz para auxiliar, mas confesso que está complicado gerar um código que fique nesse looping até que peça para parar. Este é o código atual. Acredito que precise de mais condicionais para funcionar corretamente, mas se puderem me dar uma luz de por onde começar, me ajudará muito!

```
matriz = [[' X ', '', '', '', ''],
          [1, 2, '', 3, 4],
          [5, 6, '', 7, 8],
          [9, 10, '', 11, 12],
          [13, 14, '', 15, 16],
          [17, 18, '', 19, 20],
          [21, 22, '', 23, 24],
          [25, 26, '', 27, 28]]
while True:
    for linha in range(0, 8):
        for coluna in range(0, 5):
            print(f'[{matriz[linha][coluna]:^4}]', end='')
        print()
    assento = int(input('Escolha o assento desejado: '))
        if assento in matriz:
        print(matriz[i])
    assento = matriz.replace("assento", " ")
    resp = ' '
    while resp not in 'SN':
        resp = str(input('Deseja comprar mais um assento? [Sim / Não] ')).strip().upper()[0]
    if resp in 'N':
        break
```

Comment: Listas não têm `replace`, vc precisa encontrar a posição em que o elemento está: https://ideone.com/TyyJ23 - veja que não precisa criar outra lista (que é o que a resposta abaixo está fazendo, sempre criando uma nova lista), basta encontrar a posição e substituir o elemento.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Tentei dar uma simplificada no seu código. Testei e acho que atingi o que você estava pensando. Apenas inclui um print da matriz para validação se o resultado foi alcançado após selecionar o assento.

Segue:

```
matriz = [[' X ', '', '', '', ''],
          [1, 2, '', 3, 4],
          [5, 6, '', 7, 8],
          [9, 10, '', 11, 12],
          [13, 14, '', 15, 16],
          [17, 18, '', 19, 20],
          [21, 22, '', 23, 24],
          [25, 26, '', 27, 28]]

while True:
    assento = int(input('Escolha o assento desejado: '))
    for pos, linha in enumerate(matriz):
        linha_atualizada = list(map(lambda x: "X" if x == assento else x,linha))
        if linha != linha_atualizada:
            matriz[pos] = linha_atualizada

    print(matriz)

    resp = None
    while resp not in ["S","N"]:
        resp = str(input('Deseja comprar mais um assento? [Sim / Não] ')).strip().upper()[0]
        if resp == "N":
            break
```

Espero ter ajudado